# php validate on same page and then process through different php

Tags: php, forms, validation, send

I'm very new to PHP and have managed to learn a bit on my own, but I am getting stuck going in circles on this one.  I have a form that will validate to self and show errors on the same page.  Once the information is filled and validated, I need it to be processed through a separate PHP script that will send me an email,  post the information to a .csv file, and display a confirmation page.  I currently have both of theses things working, but not together.  In other words, my form will validate to self, but the information goes nowhere.  This is obviously useless.  Separately, I can have the form do all of the other functions by setting the action to my PHP script, but it doesn't matter if the fields are filled in or not, it sends anything.  I have tried everything from sessions, functions, include, and I cannot even remember what else to get this to work.  I have even tried to set my errors to an array and then call a TRUE/FALSE function on the results in order to get it to validate and then redirect.  I have had results from validating on the same page, but sending all of the info anyway to doing nothing but showing up on a blank page.

Please do not reply that this is a repeat.  This is a problem I have been working on and researching for at least a week.  I have read many threads on this site and others and not found a working answer.
I am not looking to validate on the client side and then send through PHP.  I also need to same page validate and ensure that any previously inputted responses a are kept (which my form currently does) as there are many fields that are required.

I am posting part of my code to keep it to the necessary information.  As I said, my validation is working on its own as well as the PHP script if I set the action to run it.

This is a portion of the validation:

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {
    $childsfirstnameErr = "Child's first name is required.";
  } else {
    $childsfirstname = test_input($_POST["childsfirstname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$childsfirstname)) {
      $childsfirstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      die;  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["childslastname"])) {
    $childslastnameErr = "Child's last name is required.";
  } else {
    $childslastname = test_input($_POST["childslastname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$childslastname)) {
      $childslastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      die;  
    }
  }

   if (empty($_POST["month"])) {
    $monthErr = "Child's birthday is required.";
  } else {
    $month = test_input($_POST["month"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$month)) {
      $monthErr = "Only numbers allowed";
      die; 
    }
  }
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

This is a portion of the form:

```
<div id="Field" style="left: 0px; top: 0px"><strong>Youth's:</strong> 
        First Name: 
            <input type="text" name="childsfirstname" style="width: 220px" value="<?php echo $childsfirstname;?>"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Last Name: 
            <input type="text" name="childslastname" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo $childslastname;?>"/>
    </div>
    <div id="parent" class="error"> 
        <div id="error1a" style="right: 561px"> <?php echo $childsfirstnameErr;?></div>
        <div id="error1b"> <?php echo $childslastnameErr;?></div> 
    </div>
```

While I realize that there is no code on here to show that I am attempting to redirect for the sending of the information, please trust that I have made more than several attempts and that all I am looking for is the best manner in which to do this and some ACTUAL guidance in how to go about doing it.  So long as it works, it doesn't matter to me whether it's include or require, sessions or otherwise as long as it's PHP and 
Validates to self and then submits to another PHP script once validation is complete and form is error free.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated especially as I am doing this on a volunteer basis.  Thank you in advance to any and everyone who can offer a helping hand.

This is the beginning and the end of my PHP script - I'll leave the middle out since there are 16 essentially identically working written validations in all.
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

```
if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {
  $Err[1] = "Child's first name is required.";
 }else {
  $childsfirstname = test_input($_POST["childsfirstname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$childsfirstname)) {
    $Err[1] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
}

  if (empty($_POST["childslastname"])) {
  $Err[2] = "Child's last name is required.";
  } else {
  $childslastname = test_input($_POST["childslastname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$childslastname)) {
    $Err[2] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
}
```

. . .

```
if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
$Err[15] = "Date required.";
}else {
$date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$date)) {
  $Err[15] = "Letters are not allowed"; 
 }
}

if (empty($_POST["checkbox"])) {
$Err[16] = "VALIDATION REQUIRED";
}else {
$checkbox = test_input($_POST["checkbox"]);
 }
}  

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>
```

This is without any current attempt at passing the form information on - only with validation working.  I am continually reverting to what is working so that I don't break something that is working.

Comment: Insert the code from the second script into the first one or execute it by calling `require` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your submit button.  And also the name of your 2nd (email) php routine.  I can edit my answer to be less invasive -- I guess my intent was for you to pick out the important part.

Comment: My submit button is just a run of the mill submit button.  This has nothing to do with where the information goes.  That is done through functions.  It looks like this:<label><strong><input id="submit" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" /></strong>
</label>  I attempted to pass on the information using sessions.  This worked, but it didn't matter whether or not my form was validated, it sent on everything - even blank required fields.  However, my actual question has to do with how to get this to work.

Comment: "And also the name of your 2nd (email) php script."

Comment: I EDIT'ed my answer to give you instructions to "get it to work".

Comment: Thank you, I was editing my question to include more.  Where exactly do I put "$torf" ?  I tried it, but nothing.  Just validation and stays on the same page.

Comment: I made EDIT 2 to my answer.  If there are no validation errors, $torf should end up "true".  Maybe you can do some "echo"s to debug this.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that tried to help!  Some of the information was helpful in allowing me to find a solution.  I was able to use information from @dcromley and @Joseph_J.  I set up all of my errors as an array and then used the true/false set up suggested by @dcromley.

```
     `$Error = "false";
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $Error = "true";
      if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {
    $Error = "false";
      $Err[1] = "Child's first name is required.";    
    }else {
    $childsfirstname = test_input($_POST["childsfirstname"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$childsfirstname)) {
    $Error = "false";
    $Err[1] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
```

Then I placed a hidden text field in my html to collect the $Error = "true" or $Error = "false" and set a function to include my next php if $Error = "true".

```
<input name="Err" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Error ?>" style="width: 945px"/>
    <div id="submit">
<label>&nbsp;<strong><input id="submit" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" /></strong>
</label>
    </div>
&nbsp;</div>
</form>

 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && ($Error === "true")){ 
 enter();
 }
 ?>
```

Since I could not (for some unknown reason) get header to work, this is why I used include.  In order to hide the form once the confirmation appeared, I did this before the form and at the beginning of the form:

```
    $style = "";
    if($Error === "true"){
     $style = "style='display:none;'";
    }

?>
<div id="wrap">
<form id="RegForm" method="post" action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars  ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. I guess the "at"dcromley doesn't work except in a comment (I just stumbled back into here).  I don't get "enter();", but I'm glad you got your stuff going.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that you could do.

The first using the header() to redirect your script to the desired page.

```
if(have_valid_data){    
header('Location: email.php');
}
```

The second way would be to use something like jQuery validation Plugin to validate your form.  Then use the action attribute on the form tag to redirect to your desired page once the validation is successful.  Here is a link for the jQuery plugin.

I use this to validate all of my forms.  It is very easy to use and has a lot of features and can be customized to do just about anything you want.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

***Additional Example***

This is just an example of how one might validate a form.  You go through all of your conditions and if they generate an error then you would add that error to an array, say $errors.

If when you are done and the $errors array is empty then you did not have any errors and you can assume that your form validated.  Then you do whatever additional code that you want.  In your case you will use the header function to tell the php script to go to another page and execute the script there.

You could also use include/require and include the script from that page in the current pages code.  I would choose that option.

If there are errors in the $errors array then you display the errors.

```
//I would use one variable(an array) for your errors.
if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {

  $errors[] = "Child's first name is required.";

}

if (empty($_POST["month"])) {

  $errors[] = "Child's birthday is required.";

}

if(!isset($errors) && empty($errors)){  //<---This means you have no errors.

    //Since you have no errors you can do what you want to do with the info.
  header('Location: your_email_page.php'); 

  //OR

  //include 'your_email_page.php';  //<-- I prefer this way but sometimes header() has a purpose too.

  exit();  //End the script.

}else {

  echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>'; //<--Display your errors.

}
```

Just take the time and study this example and then apply it to your own code.

Comment: could you elaborate on what "have_valid_data" entails.  Is that actually what I put in my script?  And, I just realized that I forgot that I tried headings with not action occurring.  Also, I want to stick with PHP only, but thank you for the jQery suggestion anyway

Comment: That is just psuedo code to show you how to set up a conditional statement.  You want to write functions that return true of false for your data.  If they all return how you want them to then the form would be valid.  I will write an example for you.

Comment: I tried to set up a conditional statement and true/false returns, but it didn't submit my data.  It only brought me to a blank page,  I must have done something wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer.   Remember this is a template, just study and adapt it to your code.

Comment: I did like you said and it is not working correctly.  When I try to submit with missing data, I get an error message as expected, but when the form is full, it just brings the blank form back up without sending data anywhere or redirecting to anything.  It is also not echoing the already inputted responses anymore when some fields are put in, but the error for that field is now missing.  This seems to be the track I have been looking for, but it is not executing correctly.

Comment: Using "header", it seems to me that you will get to the 2nd php routine, but there will not be any $_POST data and that the validated form data will be lost?  Am I wrong?  (CC: @Angela S. )

Answer (score 0):

1) Remember the `isset()` function. Someone can bypass/edit your html form.

2) Never use `die` / `exit`, but for testing purposes only - or some rare cases you will have no other way around it.

3) To answer your question, your form should submit the data (form action attribute) to the same page. There you will do all your checks if you find the form is submitted and you will display appropriate errors in form and maybe even refill the inputs. Some say it's bad for security, I say it's bad for the user's experience not to refill them.

If you find the form was submit correctly, then you redirect the user to the other page using

```
header('Location: /success-script.php');
exit;
```

When using `header()`, you MUST use `exit` right after, cause you're redirecting, so you don't really want to run the rest of the code. A simple user will never know the difference if you don't. A child-hacker can easily see the results of the rest of the code and at times this is a real threat.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try the header function again as I cannot remember if I had the exit function included when I tried to use it -  I have tried so many things to this point.

Comment: As for my form validating to itself and displaying errors on the same page, that was not a question, it was a statement - it does.  Also, if I'm not supposed to use die / exit except for testing, why do you say to use it after header?

Comment: die/exit is not like a return statement, it completely stops code execution. If you kill the code execution at the moment you find the error, you will never be able to display it. But if you find everything is ok and you want to redirect to a different url, that is a different request to the server, that will open a new thread. If you don't, it's like having an element in an html form with "display:none;". It will not be visible to the simple user, but an experienced one can view it at anytime and this could be a security threat.

Comment: Yes, conflicting message there with the die/exit!

Comment: Could you please give a little more info about the message? Also I suppose you have removed the "die" statements everywhere but after the "header()" function.

Comment: Using "header", it seems to me that you will get to the 2nd php routine, but there will not be any $_POST data and that the validated form data will be lost?  Am I wrong?  (CC: @Angela S. )

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. You will make a first check (if) to see if the form is submitted. Then you will catch all errors with multiple ifs. If there were errors, you will display them in the same page (after exiting the first if I suppose). If there were not any errors, you will do all the actions with the data from the $_POST and THEN you will use header and exit this script.

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

```
IS FORM POSTED?

    YES

        IS FORM VALID?

            YES

                Process data

                HTTP redirect and exit

            NO

                Render form with errors
    NO

        Render blank form
```

At the end of your validation checks you can pass your data to other functions, then redirect, something like:

```
if(
    empty($childsfirstnameErr) &&
    empty($childslastnameErr)  &&
    empty($monthErr)
)
{
    email_the_data($data);
    store_to_csv($data);
    // Redirect and exit here.
}
```

I've added an example of a slightly adapted version of your code with just two form fields here:

https://hastebin.com/abekobuyux.xml

And here a slightly refactored version:

https://hastebin.com/agomosikim.xml

The latter style would make it easier to test each component.

Comment: How would you redirect?  Using "header", it seems to me that you will get to the 2nd php routine, but there will not be any $_POST data and that the validated form data will be lost?  Am I wrong?  (CC: @Angela S. )

Comment: @dcromley the header location redirect (PRG) here, is after completion (validaded, emailed, stored to csv).  $data could be a validated and/or filtered array of values, that other functions can use, a substitute for the super globals. Personally I'd encapsulate the logic in functions, but they could be require_once lines if needed.

Comment: The OP said: "Once the information is filled and validated, I need it to be processed through a separate PHP script that will send me an email, post the information to a .csv file, and display a confirmation page.", so I don't think she wanted the "email" and "store" in the 1st script.

Comment: All of that can be done above.  The final redirect is the confirmation page.  The processing functions can call/use other scripts/files.  Compartmentalise by all means.

Comment: Yes,  dcromley is correct.  I have a PHP - "sendemail_script.php" that contains all of the required scripting and information to "send and email, post the information to a .csv file, and display a confirmation page.  If I use <form method="post" action= sendemail_script.php>, the form will be redirected to this page where all of the above will occur.  However, as earlier stated, it does not matter whether the form passed validation or not.  It follows the action as directed in the action.

Comment: I understand the problem clearly.  As I suggest, lightly refactor your combined script.  And pass your validated/filtered $data to functions.

Answer (score 0):

This model for me I modified for you.  I hope it helps.

```
<?php // php1.php
  $torf = "false";
  $firstname = "donald";
  $lastname = "trump";
  $firstnameErr = "";
  $lastnameErr = "";
  if (isset($_POST["firstname"])) { // if submitted, validate
    $torf = "true";
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    if ($firstname != "george") {
      $torf = "false"; 
      $firstnameErr = "firstname must be george"; }
    if ($lastname != "washington") {
      $torf = "false"; 
      $lastnameErr = "lastname must be washington"; }
  }    
  echo <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  "use strict";
window.onload = function() {
  if (${torf}) { // true if php OKs it
    var elt = document.getElementsByName("myform")[0];
    elt.action = "php2.php"; // go to 2nd php
    elt.submit(); }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="myform" action="" method="post">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="${firstname}"/><br />
  Last Name: 
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="${lastname}"/><br />
  ${firstnameErr}<br />
  ${lastnameErr}<br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
?>

<?php // php2.php
  echo "Am in php2.php; \$_POST data is:<br />\n";
  echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

EDIT: (Instead of your "submit", I meant to ask you for your "form" statement.  No big deal.) I feel like the whole world but me is wrong and I am the only one right.  I am looking for anything that refutes that.  Here are instructions for you to "get it to work".

```
// #1 change this:
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// to this:
  $torf = "false";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $torf = "true";
// end

// #2 in your php code, every place that you find a validation error, insert this:
  $torf = "false";
// end

// #3 add id="formid" to your <form statement:
  <form id="formid" ..
// end

// #4 change this:
  </head>
// to this:
  <script>
  "use strict";
window.onload = function() (
  if ( <?php echo $torf; ?> ) { // true if php OKs it
    var elt = document.getElementById("formid");
    elt.action = "sendemail_script.php"; // go to email, etc.
    elt.submit(); }
}
  </script>  
  </head>
// end

// guaranteed to work! :)
```

EDIT 2:

```
// I've numbered the changes #1 to #4.  I assume you've checked them.
// > Where exactly do I put "$torf" ?
// $torf appears in changes #1, #2, and #4. Which one is unclear?

// Look at the page source in your browser
// (In chrome, I right-click and hit "view page source").
// I assume the line after "use strict"; is
  if (false) {
// correct?

//In your form, change
        First Name:
// to
        First Name: X <?php echo $torf; ?> X
// I assume that "X false X" will result, correct?

// For change # 2, your changes are like this, correct? :
// before change
  if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {
    $childsfirstnameErr = "Child's first name is required.";
// after change
  if (empty($_POST["childsfirstname"])) {
    $torf = "false";
    $childsfirstnameErr = "Child's first name is required.";

// $torf should be "true" if there are no validation errors.
// It must be getting set to "false" somewhere where it shouldn't be.
// Look for that.

// Why is it that you "die"?
// Doesn't that prevent validating the rest of the fields?
// Do you find validation errors one at a time?

// Please check for unintended "false" and I'll think about it.
```

Comment: This does not actually answer my question at all, it only completely changes what I have to something totally different and without any submission to my php script

Comment: @Angela S.  "without any submission to my php script"?  After validation, (george washington), the form data is submitted to php2.php, where your email etc. would be.  The important point is that somehow the php in php1.php must (?) communicate to the javascript in the php1.php page that the data has been validated so the form data can be submitted to php2.php.  In my model, this is done in the statements "if (${torf})", "elt.action = 'php2.php';" and "elt.submit();".  No "headers"s, no "redirect"s.